# Can you drop your current spell without using it?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In the TF2 Halloween update this year, you can pick up spells, that when cast do various things. You can only hold one type of spell at a time, and you can pick up more spells (when empty) as you roam around the map.

Is there a way to drop your current spell (like the teleport or highjump) in order to pickup a new one without using it first?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can drop them, but why not just use them up quickly? Short teleports or jumps in enclosed spaces are rather simple. You could also learn more ways to use them. Tele and jump are great for getting to hard to reach places like the enemy spawn gate, up behind enemy lines, or on top of the shack on the cliff. They are great for quick escapes and jump can actually frag enemies close to you. A well timed/aimed tele or jump can save you from death and can help you reach the spell-gate when it's heavily guarded.

Comment: @skovacs1 All your points are valid. There are just times (classes/load out/situations) when I would rather just have a new spell.

Comment: If you really want to get rid of it, just teleport/highjump to another spell :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to drop spells without using them.
The best alternative would be to just quickly use up your current spell.

EDIT: As Colin D mentioned, a rare spell (found at the clock tower during the witching hour, dropped from the skeleton king if killed, and found at certain locations in hell) will replace non-rare spells. Also, when the match advances to the hell portion of the battle you will gain a random non-rare spell (this will always replace your current spell).

Comment: It might be useful to mention that picking up a 'rare spell' will automatically replace a non-rare spell. Also, starting a new round gets rid of your current spell. Starting the hell portion of Helltower gives you a new spell at random.